# Register keyword in C++

Tags: c++

What is difference between

```
int x=7;
```

and

```
register int x=7;
```

?

I am using C++.

Comment: @GMan: ANSI C does not allow for taking the address of a register object; this restriction does not apply to C++

Comment: Voting to re-open `register` has different semantics between C and C++.

Comment: as a consequence of this, in C it's possible to forbid the array-to-pointer conversion by making an array register: `register int a[1];` with that declaration, you cannot index that array. If you try, you do UB

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In C++ as it existed in 2010, any program which is valid that uses the keywords "auto" or "register" will be semantically identical to one with those keywords removed (unless they appear in stringized macros or other similar contexts).  In that sense the keywords are useless for properly-compiling programs.  On the other hand, the keywords might be useful in certain macro contexts to ensure that improper usage of a macro will cause a compile-time error rather than producing bogus code.

In C++11 and later versions of the language, the `auto` keyword was re-purposed to act as a pseudo-type for objects which are initialized, which a compiler will automatically replace with the type of the initializing expression.  Thus, in C++03, the declaration: `auto int i=(unsigned char)5;` was equivalent to `int i=5;` when used within a block context, and `auto i=(unsigned char)5;` was a constraint violation.  In C++11, `auto int i=(unsigned char)5;` became a constraint violation while `auto i=(unsigned char)5;` became equivalent to `auto unsigned char i=5;`.

Comment: An example of the last bit may be useful.

Comment: A good article about register is here but use google translator from Czech to English, it is worthy: http://amapro.cz/public/programovani/c/register/register.php

Comment: This answer is no longer correct, since 2011, the keyword `auto` cannot be simply omitted... Perhaps you could update your answer.

Comment: @Walter: Can you cite what has changed?  I haven't followed all the language changes.

Comment: @supercat, you've missed one of the most significant changes: http://stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#auto

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Yes, of course; I knew of `auto` and type inference, but failed to make the connection. Do you know if the answer would still be true as regards `register`?

Comment: @supercat, yes, for the moment, but `register` is deprecated and there is going to be a proposal to remove it for C++17.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I wonder if it would remain as a reserved word (perhaps potentially useable with some sort of "event" concept?) or released?

Comment: @supercat, the draft proposal I've seen suggests keeping it reserved, like `export`

Comment: According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto, post C++11, `auto` is now used for automatic type deduction But before then, it was used to specify that you wanted your variable to be stored "automatically" (therefore on the *stack* I guess) as opposed to the keyword `register` (meaning "processor's register"):

Comment: How can you remove `auto` in `auto x = 5;` without breaking the code? This answer should be updated or at least edited to include which version of C++ it considers.

Answer (score 108):

`register` is a hint to the compiler, advising it to store that variable in a processor register instead of memory (for example, instead of the stack).

The compiler may or may not follow that hint.

According to Herb Sutter in ["Keywords That Aren't (or, Comments by Another Name)"](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403859):

> A register specifier has the same
>   semantics as an auto specifier...

Comment: Since C++17, it is deprecated, unused and reserved, however.

Comment: @ZachB, this is incorrect; register is reserved in C++17 but it still _works_ and functions almost identically to C's register.

Comment: @LewisKelsey It is unused and reserved in the C++17 spec; it is not one of the `storage-class-specifier` in the grammar and has no defined semantics. A conforming compiler can throw an error like Clang does. Nonetheless some implementations still allow it and either ignore it (MSVC, ICC) or use it as an optimization hint (GCC). See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0001r1.html.

I did misspeak on one point though: it was deprecated in C++11.

Answer (score 52):

According to [Herb Sutter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297582/herb-sutter), `register` is "[exactly as meaningful as whitespace](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403859)" and has no effect on the semantics of a C++ program.

Answer (score 29):

With today's compilers, probably nothing.  Is was orginally a hint to place a variable in a register for faster access, but most compilers today ignore that hint and decide for themselves.

Answer (score 15):

`register` is deprecated in C++11. It is unused and reserved in C++17.

Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/register

Answer (score 12):

Almost certainly nothing.

`register` is a hint to the compiler that you plan on using `x` a lot, and that you think it should be placed in a register.

However, compilers are now far better at determining what values should be placed in registers than the average (or even expert) programmer is, so compilers just ignore the keyword, and do what they wants.

Answer (score 5):

The `register` keyword was useful for:

- Inline assembly.
- Expert C/C++ programming.
- Cacheable variables declaration.

An example of a productive system, where the `register` keyword was required:

```
typedef unsigned long long Out;
volatile Out out,tmp;
Out register rax asm("rax");
asm volatile("rdtsc":"=A"(rax));
out=out*tmp+rax;
```

It has been deprecated since C++11 and is unused and reserved in [C++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/register).

Comment: And I would add that the 'register' keyword would only be useful on a microcontroller running a single C++ program with no threads and no multi tasking. The C++ program would have to own the whole CPU to make sure that the 'register' variable won't be moved from the special CPU registers.

Comment: @SantiagoVillafuerte do you want to add it editing the answer?

Comment: I am not that sure of my answer...although it sounds plausible. I'd prefer to leave it as a comment so that others approve it or disapprove it.

Comment: @SantiagoVillafuerte This isn't actually true, in multitasking systems when context switching the OS - not the application - is responsible for saving/restoring registers. Since you're not context switching after every CPU instruction, putting things in registers is absolutely meaningful. The other answers here (that compilers simply don't care about your opinion when it comes to register allocation) are more accurate.

Comment: The example you've shown is actually using [GCC's Explicit Register Variables extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html#Local-Register-Variables), which is different than the `register` storage class specifier and is still supported by GCC.

Comment: `register` is also not required there, and that code will produce the wrong result because it's only trying to read the low bits (`rdtsc` writes low/high bits to eax and edx, respectively) and the constraint `A` means "ax *or* dx". Instead use `uint32_t tickl, tickh; asm volatile("rdtsc":"=a"(tickl),"=d"(tickh)); Out ticks = ((Out)tickh << 32) | tickl;`.

Answer (score 4):

As of gcc 9.3, [compiling using `-std=c++2a`,](https://godbolt.org/z/QJqome) `register` produces a compiler warning, but it still has the desired effect and behaves identically to C's `register` when compiling without -O1–-Ofast optimisation flags in the respect of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61141973/7194773) answer. Using clang++-7 causes a compiler error however. So yes, `register` optimisations only make a difference on standard compilation with no optimisation -O flags, but they're basic optimisations that the compiler would figure out even with -O1.

The only difference is that in C++, you are allowed to take the address of the register variable which means that the optimisation only occurs if you don't take the address of the variable or its aliases (to create a pointer) or take a reference of it in the code (only on - O0, because a reference also has an address, because [it's a const pointer on the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57490/7194773), which, like a pointer can be optimised off the stack if compiling using -Ofast, except they will *never* appear on the stack using -Ofast, because unlike a pointer, they cannot be made `volatile` and their addresses cannot be taken), otherwise it will behave like you hadn't used `register`, and the value will be stored on the stack.

On -O0, another difference is that `const register` on gcc C and gcc C++ do not behave the same. On gcc C, `const register` behaves like `register`, because block-scope `const`s are not optimised on gcc. On clang C, `register` does nothing and only `const` block-scope optimisations apply. On gcc C, `register` optimisations apply but `const` at block-scope has no optimisation. On gcc C++, both `register` and `const` block-scope optimisations combine.

```
#include <stdio.h> //yes it's C code on C++
int main(void) {
  const register int i = 3;
  printf("%d", i);
  return 0;
}
```

`int i = 3;`:

```
.LC0:
  .string "%d"
main:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  sub rsp, 16
  mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 3
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
  mov esi, eax
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
  mov eax, 0
  call printf
  mov eax, 0
  leave
  ret
```

`register int i = 3;`:

```
.LC0:
  .string "%d"
main:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  push rbx
  sub rsp, 8
  mov ebx, 3
  mov esi, ebx
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
  mov eax, 0
  call printf
  mov eax, 0
  mov rbx, QWORD PTR [rbp-8] //callee restoration
  leave
  ret
```

`const int i = 3;`

```
.LC0:
  .string "%d"
main:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  sub rsp, 16
  mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 3 //still saves to stack
  mov esi, 3 //immediate substitution
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
  mov eax, 0
  call printf
  mov eax, 0
  leave
  ret
```

`const register int i = 3;`

```
.LC0:
  .string "%d"
main:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  mov esi, 3 //loads straight into esi saving rbx push/pop and extra indirection (because C++ block-scope const is always substituted immediately into the instruction)
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0 // can't optimise away because printf only takes const char*
  mov eax, 0 //zeroed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6212755/7194773
  call printf
  mov eax, 0 //default return value of main is 0
  pop rbp //nothing else pushed to stack -- more efficient than leave (rsp == rbp already)
  ret
```

`register` tells the compiler to 1)store a local variable in a callee saved register, in this case `rbx`, and 2)**optimise out stack writes if address of variable is never taken**. `const` tells the compiler to **substitute the value immediately** (instead of assigning it a register or loading it from memory) and write the local variable to the stack as default behaviour. `const register` is the combination of these emboldened optimisations. This is as slimline as it gets.

Also, on gcc C and C++, `register` on its own seems to create a [random 16 byte gap](https://godbolt.org/z/-kParm) on the stack for the first local on the stack, which doesn't happen with `const register`.

Compiling using -Ofast however; `register` has 0 optimisation effect because if it can be put in a register or made immediate, it always will be and if it can't it won't be; [`const` still optimises out the load on C and C++ but at file scope only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61144669/7194773); `volatile` still forces the values to be stored and loaded from the stack.

```
.LC0:
  .string "%d"
main:
  //optimises out push and change of rbp
  sub rsp, 8 //https://stackoverflow.com/a/40344912/7194773
  mov esi, 3
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
  xor eax, eax //xor 2 bytes vs 5 for mov eax, 0
  call printf
  xor eax, eax
  add rsp, 8
  ret
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a case when compiler's optimizer has two variables and is forced to spill one onto stack. It so happened that both variables have the same weight to the compiler. Given there is no difference, the compiler will arbitrarily spill one of the variables. On the other hand, the `register` keyword gives compiler a hint which variable will be accessed more frequently. It is similar to x86 prefetch instruction, but for compiler optimizer.

Obviously `register` hints are similar to user-provided branch probability hints, and can be inferred from these probability hints. If compiler knows that some branch is taken often, it will keep branch related variables in registers. So I suggest caring more about branch hints, and forgetting about `register`. Ideally your profiler should communicate somehow with the compiler and spare you from even thinking about such nuances.