# error: expected ')' before 'tokenType' in method declaration

Tags: c++, enums, compiler-errors

I am trying to take an enum member declared in another file with this method:

```
inline void register(TokenType tokenType, InfixParselet* parselet)
{
    m_infixMap.insert(tokenType, parselet);
}
```

With `TokenType` declared in another file with:

```
enum TokenType
{
  // --- Symbols ---
  TOKEN_LEFT_PAREN,
  TOKEN_RIGHT_PAREN,
  TOKEN_LEFT_SQUARE_BRACE,

  // Loads more symbols left out for conciseness

  TOKEN_NEW_LINE,
  TOKEN_ERROR,
  TOKEN_EOF
};
```

I have already checked that this file is correctly included in the file with the method in, but I still get the error: `error: expected ‘)’ before ‘tokenType’
     inline void register(TokenType tokenType, InfixParselet* parselet)
                                    ^`

This error, I believe, is common when the type hasn't been declared properly, but I can't find a problem with the declaration. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe `register` is a [keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207018/register-keyword-in-c).

Comment: @VictorPolevoy [That's right!](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`register` is a keyword which denotes automatic storage duration and hints to the compiler to store the variable in a register. You should not use it in your code as a function name. Change it to `register_token` or something and it should work.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I knew that `register` was a keyword, but I thought that the compiler would be smart enough to pick up that it was a method signature (or at least give an intelligent error message). Thanks!

Comment: Keyword identifiers are unconditionally treated as keywords except in an attribute-token.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the compiler since `register` is a keyword. (It's an optimisation adviser to the compiler to maintain a variable in a CPU register.)

Comment: Okay - thanks! That didn't register with me (pun not intended), and I hoped the compiler would be smart enough to pick that up. Thanks again.

Comment: Because `register` is rather hardwired into the C++ grammar, it would be difficult for the compiler to work out that you actually wanted to use it as a function name.