# Optimizing logical AND/OR of multiple bytes

Tags: optimization

Let's say I want to find one byte (think `memchr`) quickly. If I want that, I may:

- unroll search loop: compare multiple subsequent array elements, logically AND results, etc
- batch-compare bytes using XORing `union{uint64_t,char[8]}*` and reference consisting from the search byte repeated 8 times.

The second optimization is not effective unless I have a CPU instruction for logically multiplying all bytes (treating each byte of wide value as binary value) of a value.

Do common architectures (x86, ARM, MIPS, SPARC whatever) have extensions for this?

This question is not C-specific.

Comment: Are you asking about vector instructions?  Many platforms have them (e.g. SSEx and AVX on Intel), but they differ quite significantly from platform to platform.

Comment: Measure the speed of memchr () before you try to do anything tricky.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yes. Architecutre-specific instructions are fine.

Comment: @gnasher729 good point but not exactly the answer I am looking for. https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/memchr.c has interesting implementation though.

Comment: [Find the first instance of a character using simd](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40915243/995714), [Compare 16 byte strings with SSE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31999284/995714), [Implementing strcmp, strlen, and strstr using SSE 4.2 instructions](https://www.strchr.com/strcmp_and_strlen_using_sse_4.2). With AVX512 you can do operations on 64 bytes at once, so it's much faster than your uint64_t trick

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc make it an answer. :3