# XNOR two 64 bits registers in 8 bit blocks

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, x86-64, simd

I have two 64 bit vales and I want to XNOR them as follows:

```
RAX: 01000001 | 01000010 | 01000011 | 01000001 | 01000101 | 01000110 | 01000111 | 01000001     XNOR
RBX: 01000001 | 01000001 | 01000001 | 01000001 | 01000001 | 01000001 | 01000001 | 01000001
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RCX:    1          0          0          1          0          0          0          1



XNOR does the following:
    1 XNOR 1 | 1
    1 XNOR 0 | 0
    0 XNOR 1 | 0 
    0 XNOR 0 | 1
```

so that each time the XNOR results in  exactly `0xff` it outputs `1` in the corresponding block position in the RCX register.

Is there an I64 instruction, or an arithmetic/logic expression, to solve the problem above?

Comment: This may be better expressed as a vector compare, and [`pcmpeqb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pcmpeqb:pcmpeqw:pcmpeqd) is pretty close to what you want.  That will leave `0xff` in the bytes that compare equal, instead of `0x1`, so maybe you follow it by a vector negate; I'm not sure if there is a single instruction, but vector subtract from 0 would do.

Comment: So XNOR is just an equality comparison?

Comment: XNOR is equality on a bitwise level, yes (see the truth table).  But what you want is not really bitwise XNOR, because you want the second byte in the example to come out 0 and not `11111100`.  So I really think this is a *bytewise*, not bitwise, operation, and in that sense it makes more sense to call it compare than XNOR.  And that's also what suggests to me that SIMD is a better route than bit twiddling.

Comment: @NateEldredge: `pabsb` (byte absolute value) will map 0xff -> 1 and 0x00 -> 0.  But if they want the result in RCX, they probably want `pmovmskb ecx, xmm0` to extract the high bit of each vector byte, giving a bitmap of the compare result.  Unless they *want* 1 bit per byte separated by zeros.

Comment: Related: [Compare 16 byte strings with SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31999284) does it with intrinsics.  Use `movq` loads (or register copies from integer regs) instead of `movdqu` to only load 8 bytes, if that's really all you want.

Answer (score 3):

The "in 8-bit blocks" part of this is what makes it very different from bitwise XNOR. And you want to horizontally reduce the XNOR result with AND, in 8-bit chunks.  **This is what [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) is all about**.

The specific operation you want is compare for equality.  Fortunately, x86 SSE2 (or MMX) [`pcmpeqb xmm0, xmm1`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pcmpeqb:pcmpeqw:pcmpeqd) does exactly that, producing 0xFF (-1) in elements that compare equal, and 0x00 in other elements.  You can `movq xmm0, src` to set up for it, doing an 8-byte zero extending load into a 16-byte XMM register.

You can get the result (from the low 8 bytes of XMM0) into RCX with `movq rcx, xmm0`, where a `bsf rcx, rcx` will find the position of the lowest non-zero bit.  Or `test rcx, rcx` will let you branch if there were any non-zero bits.

If you want RCX = `0x0100000100000001` (i.e. 1 bit at the bottom of each byte), you can use [SSSE3 `pabsb xmm0, xmm0`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pabsb:pabsw:pabsd:pabsq) before MOVQ to do packed absolute value of bytes, mapping 0xFF -> 1 and leaving 0 unchanged.  Unlike SSE2, this is *not* baseline for x86-64, but CPUs that lack it are pretty thoroughly obsolete (like AMD Phenom II being the latest).

---

**The normal way to get SIMD compare results into an integer reg is [pmovmskb](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmovmskb).**  It's as efficient as `movq r, x` but lets you get all 16 byte elements without even using 64-bit registers.

```
    movq     xmm0, [rdi]       ; 8-byte load.  Use movdqu for all 16 bytes
    movq     xmm1, [rsi]
    pcmpeqb  xmm0, xmm1
    pmovmskb ecx, xmm0

    cmp      ecx, 0xffff
    je       all_were_equal

    test     cl, cl        ; low 8 bytes of compare result -> low 8 bits of RCX
    jnz      some_were_equal
```

This takes the high bit of each byte.  i.e. gives you a compare bitmap.  You can `bsf ecx, ecx` to find which (if any) of the 16 bytes was the first match.  (If your inputs were zero-extended 8-byte values, then the 9th byte will always match.  CH will be all-ones from the upper half of the pmovmskb input.)

Of course instead of bit-scanning the compare result, you can simply branch on it.  The common ways are:

- `test ecx, ecx` / `jnz` to jump if any elements compared true
- `cmp ecx, 0xffff` / `je` to jump if all matched.

Related: [Compare 16 byte strings with SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31999284) for doing this with intrinsics.

---

You *could* do this with MMX `movq mm0, [rdi]` / `pcmpeqb mm0, [rsi]`, but MMX has worse throughput than SSE2 on some of the most recent CPUs (e.g. fewer execution ports on Skylake), and you'd need a slow-ish `emms` when you're done to restore the x87 state to x87 mode.

Still, you'd be saving a `movq` if your data is naturally in 8-byte chunks so you can't naturally just do 16 bytes at a time.  And the instructions are more compact (machine-code size), as you can see in the Intel manuals for their encodings.  So if 8-byte chunks are a really good fit, and you can sink the EMMS out of a large enough loop, MMX is worth considering.   (Or if you definitely never use x87 instructions at all, not even by calling any library functions, and can skip EMMS)