# Why do I have to play with "rsp" to call a c++ function?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, masm, calling-convention

I just started my assembly journey like recently, so obviously I'm a newbie, I've been writing fairly simple and basic programs and I just noticed something weird (to me).

a program giving the count of numbers in a table ending with 111 in binary

**entry point:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

extern "C" auto _start(void *, void *)->void;

auto print_msg(char *msg) {
    std::cout << msg;
}

auto print_int(uint64_t val) {
    std::cout << val;
}

auto main()->int {
    _start(print_int, print_msg);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

**assembly:**

```
.const
_tab    dw 65535, 61951, 61949, 61925, 61927, 61734, 61735, 61728
_LENGTH = ($ - _tab) / 2
_msg_1  db 'There are ', 0
_msg_2  db ' numbers ending with 111 in binary!', 0

.code
_start proc
         push     r15
         push     r14
         sub      rsp, 32 + 16
         mov      r14, rcx
         mov      r15, rdx
         xor      rcx, rcx
         xor      r9,  r9
         lea      r8,  _tab
_LOOP:   movzx    rax, word ptr [r8]
         and      rax, 111b
         cmp      rax, 111b
         jz       _INC
         jmp      _END_IF
_INC:    inc      rcx
_END_IF: inc      r9
         add      r8,  2
         cmp      r9,  _LENGTH
         jne      _LOOP
         mov      [rsp + 32], rcx
         lea      rcx, _msg_1
         call     r15
         mov      rcx, [rsp + 32]

         sub      rsp, 8
         call     r14
         add      rsp, 8

         lea      rcx, _msg_2
         call     r15
         add      rsp, 32 + 16
         pop      r14
         pop      r15
         ret
_start endp

end
```

if I comment "sub rsp, 8" and "add rsp, 8" around "call r14" out, the program will crash immediately, that doesn't make sense to me, I want to know why it happens, and also, if I replace "mov [rsp + 32], rcx" and "mov rcx, [rsp + 32]" with "push rcx" and "pop rcx", the output will be garbage, I'm also curious about that

Comment: Don't call your function `_start`; that's the default name for the entry point (at least on Linux).  Programs that define their own `_start` don't link the standard CRT startup code, and `_start` is not even a function that can return; it's just an entry point.  TL:DR: `_start` is a confusing function name for many readers.

Answer (score 5):

The [Windows x64 calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-160) requires 16B alignment of RSP before a CALL instruction (but consequently *guarantees* `rsp%16 == 8` on function entry, after `call` pushes a return address).  This explains the `sub rsp,8` around the function call.

It also requires 32B of shadow space (aka [home space](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130830-00/?p=3363)) reserved for the use of the called function, and that's what the `sub  rsp, 32 + 16` is doing.

---

It would be smart to just combine those together, and `sub  rsp, 32 + 16 + 8` on function entry, and then don't mess with RSP until the epilogue.  (In a function that did an odd number of `push`es, that take care of the `+8` to realign the stack.)

`[rsp+32]` and higher bytes are safe from being stepped on by a `call`, lower bytes aren't.

The called function can freely make use of those 32 bytes above its return address.  That explains why you get garbled output if you just push/pop around the CALL, because then your data will be in the shadow space.

---

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for ABI / calling convention links.

Comment: Also, it would be smart to write a proper prologue/epilogue for your function. This includes `push ebp` and `mov ebp,esp` right after function entry, and `pop ebp` right before returning from it

Comment: @clockw0rk: I disagree.  x86-64 function calls usually avoid stack args so RSP isn't moving around constantly so it's usually still easy for humans to keep track of stack locations relative to RSP.  There's no need to introduce the inefficiency of setting up a frame pointer when you can just use RSP, leaving RBP free for other use.  (It's also extra code to read).  Also, this is 64-bit code so obviously `push ebp` isn't encodeable, but I'm assuming you meant `push rbp` and so on.

Comment: You are correct, I meant code for 64 bit. I did not know about the avoidance of stack args on 64 bit, was most of the time writing 32bit functions. Thanks for the hint here mister cordes, will read on about this topic.     EDIT: It says on microsofts page that the first 4 args are passed via registers, and 5th and so forth are passed on the stack. Nice, learned something new this day

Comment: Wow, yes i wondered what the point in it was, especially on -Ofast; I figured that it was for cache line alignment to prevent a split line, which would be more of a penalty than those 2 extra instructions