# Why doesn't this assembly code print the top of the stack?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64

After successfully making a "Hello, World!" program in x86-64, I wanted
to make a program that can peek at the top of the stack (without popping it, and using the `esp` register so I can learn how it works). This is the program in NASM:

```
extern GetStdHandle, WriteConsoleA, ExitProcess
section .bss
    dummy resd 1
section .text
%macro print 3
    mov rcx, %1
    mov rdx, %2
    mov r8, %3
    mov r9, dummy
    push NULL
    call WriteConsoleA
%endmacro
_start:
    mov rcx, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    call GetStdHandle

    push 65
    print rax, [x], 1

    mov rcx, 0
    call ExitProcess

NULL equ 0
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE equ -11
```

At the `print rax, [x], 1` line, `x` is replaced by something. I tried a variety of things, like `rsp`, `esp`, `rsi`, `esi`, `rsp+1`, `rsp+4`, etc. None of them worked. They either don't compile or don't print anything.

What is the correct way to do it? (note: this is solely for experimental purposes. I know I could use `push`/`pop` in this case, but I want to learn how to do it this way.)

Comment: `print rax, rsp, 1` should work. What happened? Note that you are not following standard calling convention in particular the shadow space and the stack alignment requirements.

Comment: @Jester Yeah, I'm new to assembly so I'm not sure about how to do stuff properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mov rdx, [rsp]` will load 65 into `rdx`. But *WriteConsole* expects the *address* of the string to print. So you want `mov rdx, rsp`.

One other thing that should be fixed: the stack should be aligned to 16 bytes before the call and there should be 32 bytes of empty space at the top of the stack. After the push, put `sub rsp, 40`. Then use `rsp+40` as the address to print.

Comment: Ah, how did I miss that! With `mov rdx, rsp` it still doesn't work though. It hangs when I run it

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to assembly, can you explain the alignment?

Comment: With most function calls, the stack is aligned before the call, and the call itself pushes the return address (8 bytes), so every function should subtract an *odd* multiple of 8 from the stack pointer (which is done by the push 65). However, since this is *_start*, not a normal function, I suspect that the stack is already aligned to 16 on entry, so you need to subtract an additional 8 bytes.

Comment: The answer to this question perhaps explains it better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40344385

Comment: Why do we need to "subtract an additional 8 bytes" at *_start*? And why is the `sub rsp, 40` after the push and not before it?

Comment: Assuming that _start is the entry point of the program, the alignment of the stack is controlled by the OS, rather than by the calling function. In my experience, the stack is already aligned to a multiple of 16 on entry to _start, whereas it is aligned to 8 + a multiple of 16 for any other function.

Comment: The Windows ABI requires 32 bytes of free space at the top of the stack before the call. If you put `sub rsp, 40` before `push 65`, then the 65 will be at the top of the stack, instead of the free space. You could put `sub rsp, 8` before the push and `sub rsp, 32` after the push, but there's no reason to split them up.