# Weird C++ error, unqualified ID, redeclaration

Tags: c++, file

I want to create a project, I have 3 files, a `test.cpp`, `something.h` and a `something.cpp`. here they are:

test.cpp:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define f cin
#define g cout
#include "something.h"
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    register(x);
    return 0;
}
```

something.h:

```
#ifndef __SOMETHING__H_
#define __SOMETHING__H_
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

void register(int x);
#endif
```

something.cpp:

```
#include "something.h"

void register(int x)
{
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

And here is the error I get:

```
In file included from test.cpp:4:0:
something.h:5:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘int’
 void register(int x);
               ^~~
something.h:5:15: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘int’
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:10:15: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘x’ with no type [-fpermissive]
     register(x);
               ^
test.cpp:10:15: error: redeclaration of ‘int x’
test.cpp:9:9: note: ‘int x’ previously declared here
     int x;
         ^
In file included from something.cpp:1:0:
something.h:5:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘int’
 void register(int x);
               ^~~
something.h:5:15: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘int’
something.cpp:3:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘int’
 void register(int x)
               ^~~
something.cpp:3:15: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘int’
```

Why does it tell me that I redefine x? When I just want to call register with it's value.

Comment: Unrelated: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Side comments: [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) `using namespace std`, and [cut out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives) the unnecessary use of macros

Comment: `#define g cout` could also cause you problems if register was not a reserved word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`register` is a [reserved word](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/register) in C++. Therefore, you have to give another (unreserved) name.

more information: [Register keyword in C++ - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207018/register-keyword-in-c)