# How much bad can be done using register variables in C++

Tags: c++, linux, memory

I just came to know that we can use registers, explicitly in C++ programs. I wonder what if i declare and use all available registers in a single C++ program and run it for considerable amount of time. How badly will my system behave and what (if any) measures will be taken by the os to come out of the situation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `register` keyword indicates to the compiler that the variable does not need to be addressable in main memory. Thus the compiler can be sure that there are no pointers to the value and optimize accordingly.

- [A common misconsception: the register keyword](http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/a-common-misconsception-the-register-keyword/)
- [register Keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/482s4fy9(v=VS.100).aspx) (see the non-Microsoft specific part)
- ["register" keyword in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578202/register-keyword-in-c/578648#578648)

Excessive use of the register keyword is unlikely to have serious negative impact on modern systems. Every thread maintains its own register values during execution, and its register usage will not have any direct impact on other threads. The compiler will either reject or ignore register usage that cannot result in a viable program. Poor register use will at most merely reduce performance and the OS will take no special action.

Answer (score 25):

The compiler will simply ignore the `register` keyword, so you are not going to run out of registers. It may well ignore it anyway - compilers are typically much better at register allocation than humans.

Answer (score 15):

Only specific number of Registers are available for your C++ program.

Also, it is just a suggestion for the compiler mostly compilers can do this optimization themselves so there is not really much use of using `register` keyword more because compilers may or may not follow the suggestion.

So the only thing `register` keyword does with modern compilers is prevent you from using `&` to take the address of the variable.

To Quote Herb Sutter on this:
***[Never write register. It's exactly as meaningful as whitespace](http://drdobbs.com/184403859)***

Comment: Yes. Quoting Sutter, and your paragraph on taking `&`.

Answer (score 6):

The `register` keyword is only a suggestion to the compiler and can be ignored.  Let the compiler do the optimization for you.

Answer (score 5):

The `register` keyword is only a polite suggestion to the compiler that you think this variable will be heavily used and could it pretty-please just keep it in a register.  The compiler is free to ignore this suggestion and, in fact, will usually do so in a modern environment.

`register` is basically a vestigial remnant of the old, grossly-inefficient C compilers that were available way back when.  (The same compilers that led to things like the execrable Duff's Device and other monstrosities, in fact.)  Modern compilers are far more capable than you are of keeping track of which variables should be placed into which registers at which points in execution.  They will, thus, politely ignore you without saying a word.

Answer (score 4):

Als posted a link to Herb Sutter's article on keywords. I agree with Sutter that one should never use register. I disagree with him on whether register is meaningless.

It is worse than meaningless.

I have seen code where a variable qualified with register is later used with "&". Code with dozens and dozens of variables qualified with register. And the ultimate doozy, "register volatile  foo;"

Never use "register".

Comment: Downvoted for "Never use register". register keyword is very important in embeded systems, where you intentionally deal with hardware and know it must work without any exemptions. Additionally you might be interested in this article about Duff's device where register is required: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device

Comment: @ovanes: Duff's device does not require `register`. It works quite fine (or not so fine, depending on the reader's point of view) if you get rid of the `register` specifier. The `register` specifier is only a hint, and a very weak hint, to standard C and to C++. Compilers for which `register` is anything but a weak hint (e.g., platform-specific embedded compilers) are not compliant with the standard (and they often deviate elsewhere). When you are writing code for such a compiler you aren't truly writing C/C++. You are writing in some custom language that happens to look very similar to C/C++.

Comment: I partially agree with you, but you can't just simply state: Never use "register". The point is: C/C++ were developed to be as close as possible to hardware to provide programmers with efficiency. Sure doing embedded development one sometimes uses intrinsics and compiler specific language extensions, which make the application not portable, but people still write C++ code. And that code relies on compiler aid for the specific plattform, which otherwise would make C++ unusable for that kind of platform. And that might become around 90% or cases where C++ is currently used.

Answer (score 1):

All the CPU registers are at the disposal of your program anyway, so there is nothing exceptional in using all of them. OS won't even notice it.