# Why is creating a variable using 'extern' a declaration and not a definition?

Tags: c, declaration, definition

I came across the following problem while reading ...just cant get the logic behind this.

```
auto int c;
static int c;
register int c;
extern int c;
```

It is  given that the first three are definition and last one is declaration ..how come ?

Comment: Why the downvotes?  it's a valid question for this forum.

Comment: All four are declarations. The first three are also definitions.

Comment: @Blank - It is a silly question. `extern` means defined somewhere else. Why is that not a definition?

Comment: Silly just means you know the answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last one with `extern` does not define storage for `c`. It merely indicates that `c` exists somewhere and the linker should be able to resolve it to some global `c` defined elsewhere.

If you compiled and linked a single .c file and tried to use the last `c` you'd have a linker error. With the the first 3 `c`s you would not as they have substance (they've been *defined*) in the current compilation unit.

If you'd like to learn more about `extern` and declaration vs definition here's a [good article](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/840) on the topic. To quote from that article:

> Declaration of a variable/function simply declares that the variable/function exists somewhere in the program but the memory is not allocated for them

Answer (score 3):

The keyword `extern` references the fact that the definition of the variable (or possibly function) is elsewhere; the compiler then links this declaration to a defined body in a separate file. The prior three keywords state a declaration - the variable is not defined elsewhere and therefore are not `prototypes`.

For instance, say you have a project structure like so:

```
..
-- main.c
-- client.c
-- client.h
-- server.c
-- server.h
```

When `gcc` compiles these using the header files, the header files typically will `define` the variables required for the program. This allocates a symbol that links to the `declaration` of the symbol in the .c files. This is how compilers link up various project files with `.o` objects. You may be further interested in how this all appears by using `objdump -d` (assuming you're on Linux) to debug the actual disassembled structure of your program.

Enjoy and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The first 3 statements actually allocate a place for the `int`.

The last one does not. All it does it tell the compiler is that somewhere in another compilation unit, an `int` called `c` will be defined.

If it is not defined, you'll get a linker error later on. Unsurprisingly enough, the linker will say that `c` is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

The four sentences are declarations, however the first three sentences are also definitions.

Read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_(computer_programming)) about the difference between declaration and definition.

[auto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k3ybftz(v=vs.80).aspx), [static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-a-c-program) and [register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578202/register-keyword-in-c)  are modifiers for the variable. Read de documentation about them.

[extern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable) is only declaration because you are telling the compiler that the definition of the variable or function is somewhere else - in another `C` module -.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

First three are definition because it will set aside storage for the variables.

Last one will not allocated any storage for `int c`. It will just use storage allocated and named elsewhere.