# Other semantics associated with the register keyword

Tags: c++, c, msdn

The register keyword is [deprecated and mostly ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578202/register-keyword-in-c).

But this little part of its [documentation on the msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/482s4fy9.aspx) made me wonder.

> The compiler does not accept user requests for register variables; [...]  However, **all other semantics associated with the register keyword** are honored.

What are those other semantics?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For example in C you cannot take the address of an object declared with `register` specifier.

```
void foo(void)
{
    register int a = 42;
    &a;  // constraint violation
}
```

Another example, you cannot use `register` in a file scope declaration:

```
register int b = 42;  // constraint violation

int main(void)
{
}
```

Comment: In other words, while MSVC++ eliminates any runtime disadvantage of `register`, you still have the compile-time restrictions. (And no, there are no upsides).