# Register and Auto variables in C

Tags: c, cpu-registers

Which of the following work faster?

- Program 1

Using `register`

```
int main(){
   register int i;

   for(i=0;i<=100;i++)
       printf("%d\n",i);

   return 0; 
}
```

- Program 2:

Using `auto`

```
int main(){    
    auto int i;

    for(i=0;i<=100;i++)
        printf("%d\n",i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you check and let us know? :-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a practical problem.

Comment: Read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/578202/1233508) and don't waste time trying to prematurely micro-optimize things.

Comment: [Preoptimization is the root of all evil](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely there is no difference. The `register` keyword is to specify the compiler to store the variable in the CPU register, however most modern compilers do this automatically.

As for the `auto` keyword, it is redundant, because it there by default.
So

```
float b;
```

will be the same as

```
auto float b;
```

However on such a small example it is practically impossible to see which one is faster and more intensive tests are required.

Comment: That is why it was a gentle suggestion from my side. Don't worry, My English speaking skills are horrible too, but sometime, just I come up with some good words, that's all. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Wiser heads will give more details, but basically your register int isn't going to do anything. The compiler will do what it thinks is faster, and I'll bet the same way in both cases.
You would have to be writing some extremely low-level code to make register variables make sense, since they are literally using CPU registers directly.