# Why `register` is used in DJBX33A hash algorithm?

Tags: c, hash-function, register-keyword

I see `register` is used here.

https://gist.github.com/hmic/1676398

But I don't why it is specified as `register`. It seems the reasons listed here don't apply.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-register-keyword/

Could anybody let me know why `register` is needed in the DJBX33A hash algorithm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["register" keyword in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578202/register-keyword-in-c)

Comment: It's not needed

Comment: These days, the `register` keyword is neither needed nor really helpful. The compiler probably ignores. There’s one semantic rule: you can’t take the address of a register variable. That’s obscure enough that really isn’t relevant.